# Reloading Google Map on Form Submit

Tags: jquery, google-maps

I've created a Google Map that loads markers from a JSON file and plots them when the page first loads. This bit of functionality works correctly. However, my page also includes a form and I would like to fire the getJSON request again when the form is submitted to update the map. This is the bit I can't get to work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script> 
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
        <script>
            // convert form parameters sent using getJSON method to JSON
            $.fn.serializeObject = function() {
                var o = {};
                var a = this.serializeArray();
                $.each(a, function() {
                    if (o[this.name]) {
                        if (!o[this.name].push) {
                            o[this.name] = [o[this.name]];
                        }
                        o[this.name].push(this.value || '');
                    } else {
                        o[this.name] = this.value || '';
                    }
                });
                return o;
            };          

            $(function() {
                // method to initialise map
                function initialise() {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap({
                        'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                            var self = this;
                            $.getJSON( 'http://localhost:8888/googlemaps/demo.json', 
                                $('#filter').serializeObject(),
                                function(data) { 
                                    $.each( data.markers, function(i, marker) {
                                        self.addMarker({ 'position': new google.maps.LatLng(marker.latitude, marker.longitude), 'bounds':true } ).click(function() {
                                            self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': marker.content }, this);
                                        });
                                    });
                                }
                            );
                        }
                    });
                }

                // initial map on page load
                initialise();

                // reinitialise map on form submit
                $('#filter').submit(function(e) {
                    initialise();
                    e.preventDefault();
                });          
            });
        </script>   
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id="filter">
            <select name="foo" id="foo">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

            <select name="bar" id="bar">
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
            </select>

            <input type="submit">
        </form>

        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:400px; width:100%;"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

call the `destroy`-method of the map before you initialize it again.

Answer (score 1):

The ["AJAX" Philosophy](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/basic11.htm) (from Mike Williams' v2 tutorial), would be to leave the map (don't re-initialize it), just change the displayed data (the markers).

Separate the map creation from the markers, initialize the map on page load and call your .getJSON for the original data.  On form submit (or button click), remove all the markers and call .getJSON again, passing in the appropriate data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Linuxios. That worked. Amended code for reference:

```
$('#filter').submit(function(e) {
  $('#map_canvas').gmap('destroy');
  initialise();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

I also appended the current time to the getJSON URL to prevent caching.

```
$.getJSON( 'http://localhost:8888/googlemaps/demo.json?' + new Date().getTime()
```